# Can you get paid for reporting multiple bugs for a mobile app?

Tags: manual-testing, mobile, documentation

So I'm taking a QA course for my undergrad degree and we had to choose an app to test that we haven't used before. We already found several major bugs in the app and was wondering if the mobile app developers of the fairly popular app would be willing to pay us to get the bug report document that my group has to turn in for credit. They released around 2 updates since we have tested and haven't fixed any of the bugs we discovered.

So I'm wondering if software startup companies with a large user base would agree to pay us a good amount if we shared all the bugs we found in their app since we spent hours testing and documenting them. The app uses a subscription model or pay a larger sum to get a lifetime subscription. But we don't want the in-app purchases.

I believe the app we tested is the most popular Siri alternative. So would they actually be done to reward us for discovering a bunch of bugs in their app?

Comment: Hi @btrballin, welcome to SQA. I'm afraid there is no common answer to your question and it may be closed because of that. I suggest you contact the company involved and ask there. But bear in mind most apps are free so not that much money will be lying around. Maybe better ask for (public) credit for your efforts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is highly unlikely unless they have a bug bounty program or crowd sourced testing that you could participate in.

Typically most companies, especially start ups, get defects reported on a rather regular basis from end-users for free.